# Ruby on Rails changes table names for models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Completely new to Rails, I read that it changes your table names because it makes a bunch of assumptions but I'm working with tables that were created pre-rails and are used in a PHP API so I can't change them.

I have a Class created in Rails that references the existing table and of course I get a sql error of table not found because it appends an s at the end of the table name, so I went ahead and put this in my Class definition:

```
class BookSubjects2title < ActiveRecord::Base
set_table_name "book_subjects2title"
belongs_to :bookSubjects
end
```

Supposedly, that should take care of the problem from what I've read. Yet it doesn't, it still keeps trying to use the name with the s at the end and I get an error from the rails console. Is there anything I need to do for Rails to read this new config? Should be dynamic no?

Comment: Not sure about that, so a few comments: Have a look at `config/application.rb` and the configuration `config.active_record.pluralize_table_names = false`. Perhaps that is sufficient. Next: `belongs_to :bookSubjects` should be: `belongs_to :book_subjects`.

Comment: Thanks, I shall look, but the belongs to indicates the table name or the Class name? This is something I'm not clear on. I added that config line you wrote into the config/application.rb and still the same thing. Seems fishy that it would be ignoring everything no? But the rest of the app (such as it is) seems to work.

Comment: Aha, quitting the console and starting it up again seems to have done the trick. It now reads the table properly. Thanks a lot. If you want to go ahead and answer the question I can give you credit for it (people in this forum seem REALLY serious about that)...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your only issue but

```
belongs_to :bookSubjects
```

should never have an 's',  use this instead.

```
belongs_to :book_subject
```

Comment: this was a question I posted above in the comments, the belongs_to has to point to the table name or the Class name?